# Magnetic field everywhere around a circular curent loop

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, integration, calculus

It's pretty easy to find the expression for the magnetic field created along the axis of a circular loop of current: [image]

(a is the radius of the loop and alpha is the angle between the radius and the vector r that goes from a point on the loop to a point on the axis)

However, I'm looking for a way to describe the field everywhere around the loop. I tried integrating with Biot-Savart's law, but I feel this is not a problem meant to be tackled with the limited calculus knowledge I hold.
Does anyone know the expression that gives the field anywhere in space? How do you derive it?

Comment: [Simple Analytic Expressions for the Magnetic Field of a Circular Current Loop](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/api/citations/20010038494/downloads/20010038494.pdf)

Comment: [Calculation of off-axis Fields](https://phys.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Electricity_and_Magnetism/Book%3A_Applications_of_Maxwells_Equations_(Cochran_and_Heinrich)/05%3A_The_Magnetostatic_Field_II/5.02%3A_Calculation_of_off-axis_Fields)

Comment: The answer has long been in the problem 2 of §29 of the classic Landau Lifshitz book (Electrodynamics of Continuous Media).